# Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not supported for this instance type : [AWS Cloudformation]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a an t2.micro ec2 instance with amazon linux as os using cloudformation . Following  is the json file (parts that matter).

```
    "FileName" :{
        "Type" : "String",
        "Default" : "cf-file.sh",
        "AllowedValues": [ "cf-file.sh"]
    },
    "InstanceType" : {
      "Description" : "WebServer EC2 instance type",
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default" : "t2.micro",
      "AllowedValues" : ["t2.micro"],
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
    },

       "AMIID" :{
         "Type": "String",
        "Default":"ami-1ecae776",
        "AllowedValues":["ami-1ecae776"]
    }
  },
  "Resources" : {
    "EC2Instance" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "UserData" : {
                "Fn::Base64" : {
                    "Fn::Join" : [ 
                            "", 
                            [
                                "#!/bin/bash\n",
                                "yes y | yum install dos2unix\n",
                                "touch ",{ "Ref" : "FileName" },"\n",
                                "chmod 777 ",{ "Ref" : "FileName" },"\n" 
                            ]
                    ]
                 } 
        },
          "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "ImageId" : { "Ref" : "AMIID" }
      }
    },
```

When i run this file i get following error

```
Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not supported for this instance type
```

I guess this error comes when we use t1 family instance type but i am using t2.micro. Please explain the reason why is it so ?

Comment: Just a guess: The AMI you picked is back HVM SSD backed, which is not supported by t2. Check the HVM instance store ami: Compare 
http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/ to http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/?nc2=h_ls

Comment: @Frank what does the phrase "back HVM SSD backed" mean?  I understand HVM and SSD of course, but I am not quite sure what the whole thing means.

Comment: i have created instance( t2.micro ) using the same ami id before using aws management console @Frank

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"**InstanceType**" attribute is missing in Properties section of Resources. Therefore, It might be taking default instance type(m1.small) that does not support '**HVM**' virtualization type. I faced the similar issue, fixed it by adding Instance Type attribute. 
Also,'**t2.micro**' instance type does not support instance-store root device.
Please refer to sample snippet below for reference:

---

```
"Parameters":{
    "ServerKeyName":{
        "Description" :"key pair to connect to  Server",
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
    },
    "InstanceType" : {
        "Description" : "Type of EC2 instance to launch",
        "Type" : "String",
        "Default" : "t2.micro"
    },
    ....
    ....
}
....
....
"Properties" : {
    "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "ServerKeyName" },

    "Tags" : [
    {
        "Key" : "Name",
        "Value" : "test Server"
    }],

    "ImageId" : { "Ref" : "InstanceAMI" },
    "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "InstanceType"},
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs across this error while trying to build a Packer ami.
Make sure your template file is named with a packer extension and not json.

For instance, "packer build template.json" was failing with

> Error launching source instance: InvalidParameterCombination: Non-Windows instances with a virtualization type of 'hvm' are currently not supported for this instance type. status code: 400, request id:

Whereas packer build template.packer works just fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this relates to the original question?

Comment: I assume using cloud formation to build an AMI is similar to building one with Packer. I was trying to achieve the same thing as the OP, but was using packer instead of cloud formation. And that exact error brought me to this thread. In my particular case I was using an hvm t2.micro, but still getting the error.

Comment: This might have been a problem once, but it appears that at least as of version 0.12.3, packer works just fine with files ending in '.json'.